# Slick slider overlapping images with angular strap

Tags: angularjs, slick.js, angular-strap

I have a problem implementing angular strap and slick carousel. I have angular strap for handling tabs and slick carousel for each content of different tabs.
The problem is that when I change the tab, it shows me the images of the slick carousel one over the other. 
I cant figure out what the problem is, could anyone help me?
The problem in photo:
[image]

My tabs controller:

```
app.controller('TabsVinoteca', function($scope, $templateCache) {   

 $scope.tabs = [
    {title:'VINOS', 
    page: 'views/vinoteca/vinos.html'},
    {title:'ESPUMANTES',
    page: 'views/vinoteca/espumantes.html'}
    ];
});
```

My slick carousel controller code:

```
app.controller('SlickWinery', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.slickConfig3Loaded = true;
  $scope.slickCurrentIndex = 1;
  $scope.slickConfig = {
  autoplay: false,
  dots: false,
  nextArrow: '<span class="right slick-next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>',
  prevArrow: '<span class="left slick-prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></span>',
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '40px',
    slidesToShow: 3
    }
   },
  {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
       arrows: false,
       centerMode: true,
       centerPadding: '40px',
       slidesToShow: 1
    }
  }
   ],
          method: {},
          event: {}
 };


 });
```

My html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="sliderBrands" ng-controller="SlickWinery">

<h4>VINOS</h4>

 <div class="col-lg-12 hoverGray">
  <slick class="slider" settings="slickConfig" ng-if="slickConfig3Loaded" dots="true">
    <div>   
      <a href="#" tabindex="1"><img ng-src="img/home/bodegas/1.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div>   
      <a href="#" tabindex="2"><img ng-src="img/home/bodegas/2.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div>   
      <a href="#" tabindex="3"><img ng-src="img/home/bodegas/3.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div>   
      <a href="#" tabindex="4"><img ng-src="img/home/bodegas/4.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div>   
      <a href="#" tabindex="5"><img ng-src="img/home/bodegas/5.png"/></a>
    </div>
   </slick>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what's getting rendered from inspector? I'll bet your carousel is there but it initializes before the images have loaded so those containers don't have a size. Another thing you can try to do is put a hard height value on the slick divs.

Comment: Wait, nm, I've had this issue when trying to render angular-slick inside a Bootstrap tabbed content component. You need to switch over to vanilla Slick and use $timeout to force the init to wait until after the tabbed content has done its thing. Slick has to evaluate the dimensions it lives in then set inline height/widths to all of its pieces. If the dimensions it lives in are in flux while it renders then it delivers all wonky.

Comment: It happens if you nest Angular-Slick sliders too. I know because I've never seen a carousel that an art director didn't want to shove five more carousels into.

Comment: If used intentionally/consciously, $timeout is pretty badass: [Loupe demo](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

Comment: Hi @NominalAeon in the inspector shows me style="width:0px" but i try change in my master css, in slick.css and in style properties of div element and try to force with "!important" and don't work!! I'm desperate!! Thanks for answering!!

Comment: Try making it outside the tabbed content. Collapsed tabs have a width of 0, so Slick is all like "well, I guess I'm 0 now"

Comment: I try it, but dont work. I have two tabs and in first tab works fine but when i change in second tab the width is 0. :,(

Comment: Right, you need to do that timeout-and-set every time the tabs containers are expanded/collapsed. When collapsed the containers are 0 in size, so Slick units at 0 in size

Comment: The reason Angular-Slick uses `ng-if` is because it removes that element from the DOM completely, thus destroying the carousel. When the `ng-if` is true, it adds it to the DOM and Slick initializes. You need that `ng-if` to be false when the tab container isn't active and true after the tab container has been rendered/has dimensions for Slick to use. There should be a "afterTabToggled" sort of event to hook into, or you can use $timeout to just force it to wait for the other JavaScripts in the callstack to run.

Comment: The trick is to set that $timeout when a tab is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timeout(function () {
    slickConfig1Loaded = true;
});
```

The `ng-if` is there to prevent Slick from initializing too soon. Try putting the `true` assignment in a timeout so it gets put on the bottom of the callstack, after the tabbed content has had a chance to give its containers dimensions. Slick needs them dimensions.

////

Also, in your JS you say `slickConfig3Loaded` but in the HTML you say `slickConfig1Loaded`, is that a typo in the code or your Stack question?

Comment: Its a typo error in stack question @NominalAeon, I'll try what you tell me, thank you very much indeed for your help.

Comment: You can do eet!

Comment: Sorry @NominalAeon but I cant figure out where I should add the time function, nor how to intercept the tab click since I only have two divs: `<div class="container" ng-controller="TabsVinoteca">
    <section id="tab">
      <div class="bs-docs-example">
        <div ng-model="tabs.activeTab" bs-tabs>
           <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" data-title="{{ tab.title }}" name="{{ tab.title }}" ng-include='tab.page' bs-pane>
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </section>
</div>`

Comment: You want the `onShow` event that AngularStrap gives you. You won't even need a $timeout if you use that, it's sending out an event broadcast once the tab's content is rendered. Hook into that event and a.) set all the other `slickConfigLoaded` values to `false`, then b.) set the active tab's `slickConfigLoaded` to `true`. Read up on it [here](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/), and I bet it's pretty Google'able. That event probably passes you the active tab too but I dunno, do a `console.log` of whatever it passes you and see whatcha got.

Comment: I hope you didn't get discouraged. This is a rough problem because it's equal parts beginner and advanced in its solution. I hope you can get your head around it though, there's a lot of Angular fundamentals at play here that will really level you up once you get it. Good luck!